# Flex Blazeds java.lang.ClassCastException: flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject cannot be cast to

Tags: apache-flex

I have this problem coming up when i deploy flex java application and access through SSL. Else i dont get this problem. Cant copy the code due to some restrictions. Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<serialization>
     <instantiate-types>false</instantiate-types>
</serialization>
```

This attribute in channel definition set to false will not cast the flex VO's into java VO's in case of collections. Once when its set to true, everything starts working smoothly.It was failing only in HTTPS because the above mentioned attribute was specified only in secure amf channel, but not in HTTP amf channel.